# What's the correct way of creating a ConfigMap from a file using a YAML syntax?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can create a ConfigMap without issues with `kubectl create configmap settings --from-file settings.yaml`, but I don't want to manually create it but as part of a `helm install`.

So, I created a template file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.settingsConfigMap }}
data:
  settings.yaml: |-
{{ .Files.Get "settings.yaml" | indent 4}}
```

but whenever I run `helm install` I get an error saying that

> invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data: got "map",
> expected "string"

So, what can I do to create this ConfigMap with Helm loading the content from a YAML file?

**UPDATE**

It turns out the error mentioned above is related to some issues with the indentation. By removing the `indent 4`, I managed to get a step further, but now it's failing because all my settings are detected as `unknown fields`, for example:

> unknown field "customers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap, ValidationError(ConfigMap): unknown field "deploy_name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap, ValidationError(ConfigMap): unknown field "system" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap

`deploy_name`, `system` and `customers` are the top level keys of my settings.yaml file.

Comment: Which helm version are you using? Can you try to update to newer? It works for me with v3.2.4

Comment: @thomas `version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3.4", GitCommit:"a61ce5633af99708171414353ed49547cf05013d", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.15.2"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

The error mentioned in the update is the outcome of removing `indent 4`. By removing that, the YAML used by Helm is screwed up, hence that's why it doesn't understand those fields.

So, why did it fail when I had the `indent 4`? The reason is the missing white space before the `}`. With `{{ .Files.Get "settings.yaml" | indent 4 }}`, everything is good.